# Need to optimize CPU utilization for compressing payload to Event Hub

Tags: java, gzip

Context: I wrote multithreaded application with 1 of the thread is used to send compressed data to eventhub every x seconds.

Payload size ~ 4 MB

VM CPU utilization without compression = 55%
VM CPU utilization with compression > 100%

Note: I keep getting spikes in CPU utilization whenever data is getting compressed (I get to this conclusion by running same tests on compressed and uncompressed code)

Code snippet:

```
private void writeAndSendMetrics(StringBuilder resultJSON) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        String postBody = resultJSON.toString();
        if (!isJSONValid(postBody)) {
            logger.info("postBody is not a valid JSON {} ", postBody);
            return;
        }

        logger.debug("Request received for writeAndSendMetrics");
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
        httpPost.setURI(new URI(eventHubUrl));
        logger.debug("Result JSON: {}", resultJSON);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        StringEntity uncompressed = new StringEntity(postBody);
        logger.info("Uncompressed-size = " + uncompressed.getContentLength() );
        httpPost.setEntity(new GzipCompressingEntity(uncompressed));
        //httpPost.setEntity(uncompressed);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        logger.info("Compression-Time = " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms" );
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "xyz");
        org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
        logger.info("Response Status Code : {}", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
```

Using GzipCompressingEntity class to compress my payload. This compression is causing spikes in CPU utilization hence impacting overall throughput for other tasks or processes.

How can I optimize or decrease the CPU utilization?

Comment: Ankur, is this question really related to ADX or even to EH? It seems more like a Java related question...

Comment: Our use case is to increase the throughput to ADX eventually, looking for end to end solution. Included event hub and ADX if they had an end-to-end solution with bottle neck being compression

Comment: I suggest leaving this post for the compressing challenge and post a new question for the more broad question. Please make sure to supply some relevant information such as your current & target throughput, your implementation constraints, previous attempts result etc.

Comment: Compression takes processing power, what do you expect exactly? While you can improve responsiveness via allowing other threads to run (like having multiple virtual cores, as gzip/deflate doesn't scale to multiple threads), overall throughput won't change without making the system more beefy.

Comment: I'm missing how you have not answered your own question. Don't compress.

Comment: I am just trying to make sure that i am not doing anything wrong with my code. May be some other library or can structure my multithreading application such that i can cap compression thread not interfering with other threads.